# How to check if flutter toast already on screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show a toast message on my app whenever right condition is met based on some integer values calculation. This condition is met often and I want to show a toast message onScreen. I chose [flutter toast](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast) plugin for this. But sometimes the method is sending too many toast that toast message consists even after the app is closed. So I want to know if a toast message already on screen and cancel if so.

How do I check if flutter toast already on screen?

Alternatively please suggest me other dialogue showing way on flutter.

```
//check if exist then cancel. Or show.
Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "This is condition met Toast",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16.0
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

please take static bool isShowToast and make it false while when you call toast make their condition

```
if(!isShowToast){
 isShowToast=true;
 Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: value).then((value){
 isShowToast=false;
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run `Fluttertoast.cancel()` to cancel all toasts.

If you want only one toast to show at a time, you can run that immediately before calling showToast.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the `FluttertoastPlugin.java` https://github.com/PonnamKarthik/FlutterToast/blob/master/android/src/main/java/io/github/ponnamkarthik/toast/fluttertoast/FluttertoastPlugin.java

add the `cancel` method before `showToast`